# How to achieve the attached view with Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I can't seem to achieve the form that I want using Angular Material,
Bootstrap or HTML/CSS way is a piece of cake, but using AM I'm finding it hard to manipulate with custom forms.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opda5.png)

Link that I'm trying to achieve the form that I want
https://stackblitz.com/angular/nlylvgoqjkl?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-selection-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The way I solved is by adding a container, header,
td mat-cell and inside it create thecontent

It might not be the right approach but it will do the work

```
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <img src="sdfsdf.png">
      <tr>
<td><img src="Sdfsfsdf.png"></td>
      </tr>
       </td>
  </ng-container>
```